# Can't pass data through to material dialog - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I cannot get my Material Dialog to work. Is there something I am missing?

**product-thumbnail.ts** *I will click this to open the dialog*

```
export class ProductThumbnailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product: Product;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openPopup(prod) {
    this.dialog.open(ProductPageComponent, {
      autoFocus: true,
      width: '400px',
      data: {product: prod}
    });

  }

}
```

**product-page.ts** *This is the dialog component*

```
export class ProductPageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() product: Product;

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProductPageComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAddToCart() {
    this.cartService.addToCart(this.product);
  }

}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/shopping-app)

[image]

Comment: What problem are you seeing? Is the dialog not opening, or is it opening but not doing what you expect?

Comment: The dialog opens but I can't see data

Comment: Can you should the Module that registers ProductPageComponent ? 
The error states that you have not included it as an entryComponent

Comment: Here is the stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/shopping-app

Comment: Add ProductPageComponent into entryComponents of you `app.module`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stackblitz you provided you are missing the animations dependency

I forked from what you submit and updated the dependency and add the ProductPage Component into Entry Components of your app module.

https://shopping-app-lypbxe.stackblitz.io

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductPageComponent
..
  ],
  entryComponents: [ProductPageComponent],
  imports: [
..
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Ah great! The dialog is now popping up as intended. However, it seems I haven't routed my data correctly, so I will have to figure that one out.